# Jquery: append text into input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to append text into input after radio check.
Any idea? http://plnkr.co/edit/HvEBQa2pF43QfiNuFrkT?p=preview

```
$("#opt1").click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#result").append("Option1 is checked");
  }
});
```

Comment: if #result is input try `$("#result").val("Option1 is checked");`

Comment: better use `change` than `click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `change` event on radio buttons
2. Use `val()` to set the value of textbox
3. Make the code dynamic using the `parent()` and `text()` instead of binding event on each radio button individually.

**Code:**

```
// When the radio button state changes
$(":radio").change(function () {
    // Get the text associated with selected radio and set it
    // as value of the textbox
    $("#result").val($(this).parent().text().trim() + " is checked");
});
```

[**Updated Plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/17a1YFpEvZYoiFW62YJJ?p=preview)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":radio").change(function() {
    $("#result").val($(this).parent().text().trim() + " is checked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />

<div class="col-lg-12">
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input id="opt1" type="radio" name="optradio">Option1
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input id="opt2" type="radio" name="optradio">Option2
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input id="opt3" type="radio" name="optradio">Option3
  </label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <input id="result" type="text" class="form-control" value="" autocomplete="off" disabled/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use callback function of `.val()` to append value in input element:

```
$("#opt1").click(function(){
 if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
  $("#result").val(function(i,o){
    return o +"Option1 is checked";
  });
});
```

Comment: Why `$(this).is(':checked')`? Can you uncheck radio?

Comment: @Tushar: it can be via code `.prop( "checked", false );`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#opt1").click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#result").val("Option1 is checked");
  }
});
```

`append()` is used to add another element to that element. What you want to do is set the value of that `input` element, so use `.val()` instead.

Comment: Why `$(this).is(':checked')`? Can you uncheck radio?

Comment: I just used the OP his code, didn't bother to change it since that wasn't what he asked.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.append()` try `.val()` like this:

```
  $("#opt2").click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#result").val("Option2 is checked");
    }
  });
```

You don't actually need to used `.is(":checked")` in this case though. You could use.

```
  $("#opt2").click(function(){
      $("#result").val("Option2 is checked");
  });
```

Comment: Why `$(this).is(':checked')`? Can you uncheck radio?

Comment: Well, you don't need that in this case really. I just changed your original code to use .val() instead.

This will also work.

      $("#opt2").click(function(){
          $("#result").val("Option2 is checked");
      });

Comment: You can replace `$(this).is(":checked")` with `this.checked`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#opt1").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#result").val("Option1 is checked");
        }
    });

    $("#opt2").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

            $("#result").val("option 2 is checked");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to append text to input. First you have to get the existing value of input and concatenate it with new value i.e

```
$("#opt1").click(function(){
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $('#result').val($('#result').val() + 'Option1 is checked')
   }
});
```

Comment: Why `$(this).is(':checked')`? Can you uncheck radio?

Comment: it's included in the question, because he wants to append text only when radio is checked.

Comment: It's not checkbox, its radio button.

Answer (score 1):

By now the other answers have already resolved the issue. My post is just to show you that with a minor change you can reduce the number of lines of code

**HTML** changes

```
// Added an attribute data-text which will be captured on checking radio button
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input id="opt1" type="radio" data-text="Option 1" name="optradio">Option1
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input id="opt2" type="radio" data-text="Option 2" name="optradio">Option2
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input id="opt3" type="radio" data-text="Option 3" name="optradio">Option3
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12">
      <input id="result" type="text" class="form-control" value="" autocomplete="off" disabled/>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
// fired if there is a change  in inputs with same name
$('input[name=optradio]').change(function(){ 
   // get the data-text attribute of the checked radio button
    var _getId = $('input[name=optradio]:checked').attr('data-text');
  // Update the result input with this value
    $("#result").val(_getId +" is checked")
  })
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hmI6VsKmjBFIlloWf9ZA?p=preview)